How to prevent the author list from overflowing outside the page margin in a quarto / pandoc document when rendered to pdf?
I am writting an article as a quarto document and I want to export it to pdf. Quarto uses pandoc for rendering, so people who know about pandoc but not about quarto might still be able to help me.
In the YAML preamble, I have a long author list that overflows outside of the page when rendered to PDF.
Reproducible example, save this document to "article.qmd":
---
title: "What a nice day"
author: First name1 Name, First name2 Name, First name3 Name, First name4 Name, First name5 Name, First name6 Name, First name7 Name, First name8 Name, First name9 Name
---

bla bla bla

Render it with quarto:
quarto render article.qmd --to pdf

Or render it with pandoc:
pandoc article.qmd -o article.pdf

As a result, the author list continues outside the page instead of wrapping

Note:
$ quarto --version
1.5.57


I should have read the documentation https://quarto.org/docs/journals/authors.html. Authors should be provided as a list as follows:
---
title: "What a nice day"
author:
    - First name1 Name
    - First name2 Name
    - First name3 Name
    - First name4 Name
    - First name5 Name
    - First name6 Name
    - First name7 Name
    - First name8 Name
    - First name9 Name
---


bla bla bla

